# swift - JSON to NSManagedObject

Tags: ios, json, swift, core-data, tableview

I have a JSON data which I want to map to CoreData when my tableview loaded at first launch.
I found a way to do it in cellForRowAtIndexPath, but this way I can only save the data to CoreData when the cell is displayed.
I want to do it once for all cells.

```
    var yazarMakaleListesi: [JSON]? = []
    var authorList = [AuthorList]() // My CoreData

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("YazarCell") as! YazarTableViewCell     
        cell.yazar = self.yazarMakaleListesi?[indexPath.row]

        cell.yazar = self.yazarMakaleListesi?[indexPath.row]
        let authorName = self.yazarMakaleListesi?[indexPath.row]["author_name"].string
        let authorID = self.yazarMakaleListesi?[indexPath.row]["author_id"].int
        let authorImage = self.yazarMakaleListesi?[indexPath.row]["author_image"].string
        let newspaperID = self.yazarMakaleListesi?[indexPath.row]["newspaper_id"].string
        let newspaperName = self.yazarMakaleListesi?[indexPath.row]["newspaper"].string
        let newsPaperImage = self.yazarMakaleListesi?[indexPath.row]["author_image"].string

        let articleEntity = NSEntityDescription.entityForName("AuthorList", inManagedObjectContext: self.context!)
        let newAuthor = AuthorList(entity: articleEntity!, insertIntoManagedObjectContext: self.context!)

        newAuthor.authorName = authorName!
        newAuthor.authorImage = authorImage!
        newAuthor.newspaperName = newspaperName!
        newAuthor.newsPaperImage = newsPaperImage!
        newAuthor.authorID = authorID!

        var saveError: NSError?
        self.context!.save(&saveError)

        if let _error = saveError {
            println("\(_error.localizedDescription)")
        } else {
            println("Author Saved!")
        }

        var error: NSError?
        let request = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "AuthorList")
        let results = self.context!.executeFetchRequest(request, error: &error) as! [AuthorList]

    return cell
    }
```

I get the JSON data here:

```
   func loadYazar(){ 
        if (gazeteid != nil){
            let url = "http:myapi.com" + String(gazeteid)
            Alamofire.request(.GET, url).responseJSON { (Request, response, json, error) -> Void in
                if (json != nil){
                    var jsonObj = JSON(json!)
                    if let data = jsonObj["authors"].arrayValue as [JSON]?{
                        self.yazarMakaleListesi = data
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
   }
```

EDIT : I get my jsonresponse here, implemented @ thefredelement's recommendation.
But I get " 'JSON' does not have a member named 'valueForKey'" from line:

newFakeCoreDataObject.authorName = jsonResult.valueForKey("authorName") as! String

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, url).responseJSON { (Request, response, json, error) -> Void in
    if (json != nil){
        var jsonObj = JSON(json!)
        if let jsonResults = jsonObj["authors"].arrayValue as [JSON]?{
            self.yazarMakaleListesi = jsonResults
            var error : NSError?
            for jsonResult in jsonResults {
                let newFakeCoreDataObject = FakeCoreDataObject()
                newFakeCoreDataObject.authorName = jsonResult.valueForKey("authorName") as! String
                self.context!.save(&error)                          
            }                 
                self.tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

Comment: If you want to do it once, do it outside of `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: I'm not sure what the values are, my example was just to show you how to create a new nsmanaged object for each JSON object you received in the for loop. Yours are listed in your cell for row at index path ("author_name" , "author_id" ) etc. You should use the properties from your cell for row at index path to setup the object in the for loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would highly suggest taking that work out of cellForRowAtIndex path and making a separate function that will iterate through your JSON results and save them each, then load the data from core data as a custom object and put that object into an instance array, then use that array for your table data.

Edit: I wouldn't use this code exactly obviously, it's just an example of what I was trying to explain.

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class FakeCoreDataObject : NSObject {

// this would really be your NSManagedObject subclass
var authorName = ""
var authorImage = NSData()
var newspaperName = ""
var newspaperImage = NSData()
var authorId = 0 as NSNumber

}

class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

var myEntries = [FakeCoreDataObject]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    fetchJson()
    prepareTableData()
}

func fetchJson() {

    let appDel  = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDel.managedObjectContext!

    var error : NSError?

    // Get your json reuslts like you are already
    var jsonResults = [AnyObject]() // just for an example

    for jsonResult in jsonResults {

        let newFakeCoreDataObject = FakeCoreDataObject()
        newFakeCoreDataObject.authorName = jsonResult.valueForKey("authorName") as! String
        // etc

        context.save(&error)
        // save whatever else you want for other entities, etc, if you need track out of scope you can do that and then save after the loop

    }
}

func prepareTableData() {

    let appDel  = UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate as! AppDelegate
    let context = appDel.managedObjectContext!

    var error : NSError?

    let fetchTableDataRequest = NSFetchRequest(entityName: "whateverItIsCalled")
    fetchTableDataRequest.returnsObjectsAsFaults = false

    myEntries = context.executeFetchRequest(fetchTableDataRequest, error: &error) as! [FakeCoreDataObject]

    // If you need to do this often, reload the table data here too and you can call it from notifications, etc.
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return myEntries.count
}


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    // cell stuff you already have but just use the array
    // just a tip to set set values to "" or nil if you're creating a big table so you don't get duplciate data while scrolling
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


}
```

Comment: Ok Thank you, but I couldn't do this without using indexPath.row

Comment: Sure you can, I'll update my answer for you with some code.

Answer (score 0):

you should parse the json you receive inside responseJSON:

```
let jsonObj = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(json, options:NSJSONReadingOptions(rawValue: 0), error: &err) as! NSDictionary
                callback(jsonObj as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>, nil)

var recs:NSArray = jsonObj.objectForKey("authors") as! NSArray
var ct:Int = 0
for item in recs{
    var dict:NSDictionary = item as! NSDictionary
    // use self.yazarMakaleListesi[ct] here
    // process into the dict  "author_name" , "author_id", etc
    // increment ct
}
self.tableView.reloadData()
```